# Android UIModeManager and Application Configuration

Tags: android, configuration

I need my app to automatically switch between night/day modes.
According to the documentation I can use [UiModeManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/UiModeManager.html) like this:

```
UiModeManager uiModeManager = (UiModeManager) getSystemService(UI_MODE_SERVICE);        
uiModeManager.setNightMode(UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
```

However, the application don't use alternative resources with "night" qualifier. I didn't notice that the application actually changed the configuration.
How can I force the app to use night-qualified resources?

Answer (score 1):

Car or Desk mode must also be active in order for that mode to be effective.

Comment: Yeah, I read about it in the Android docimentation, however calling `uiModeManager.enableCarMode(0);` before setting night mode didn't cause changes in configuration. The app still runs in "normal" uiModeType. Thanks for you answer!